# What does the "free" in *free abelian group* or *free group* mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am asking for the definition of "free". What is the difference between, say, any old abelian group, and a free abelian group?

Comment: A free abelian group is the same as a product of infinite cyclic group, i.e. a product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. A free group is a bit more complicated.

Comment: See also [Why are free modules called “free”?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1354809/264)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means there are no constraints on the way generators combine to form new group elements. Such constraints in a non-free group would be given in terms of presentation relations which restrict that some combinations of generators give the identity. In a free group, every combination is unique.